# How to derive cluster properties

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have clustered ~40000 points into 79 clusters. Each point is a vector of 18 features. I want to 'derive' the characteristics of each cluster - the prominent features/characteristics of the clusters. Are there machine-learning algorithms to derive this?

Comment: Could you please indicate which technology you are using?

Comment: Also, the Cross Validated community may be able to help too.

Comment: *What* characteristics. This is not well-defined. For example, the size and the mean are trivial "characteristics" you do not need an algorithm to "derive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confident the clusters are meaningful for your particular needs, you could view it as a classification problem.

One option would be to apply a feature selection algorithm to rank the features. You could use recursive feature elimination to identify a subset of features that are predictive for the cluster labels.

Another good option for interpreting the clusters could be building a decision tree. With decision trees you can see what features are used to best separate the classes (clusters in your case). You could also use an ensemble like Random Forest and ask for feature importance scores.

Comment: Thanks Dave and to all those who asked questions. I was thinking along the lines of getting the centroid-parameters (feature weights) and use that (may as-is) as a representation of the cluster. I shall think about (and digest) David's comments. To answer others' question: I think, it doesn't matter what tech I am using. My coding practices span R, Python and more recently Scala. For now, all I am looking for is ideas...which I can try on my data and see what  works well.